# Nexus One Dev Phone vs. a regular Nexus One Phone (retail version)

Tags: android, dev-phone

**The specifics of the Nexus One Dev Phone compared to a regular N1 Phone**

I'd like to buy a N1 Dev Phone for dev purposes but also for ordinary everyday usage. So are there any specifics in the Dev Version of N1 I should care about? Is there anything that would inhibit a regular day to day usage and what are the differences to the regular retail version of the Phone?

Apart from:

- SIM unlocked - Put any SIM in the device
- Test out your apps on real hardware before publishing them to the world
- Ability to see copy protected Android Market apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, the Nexus One is only one Product, there isn't a special developer edition, with the only differences being vendor "lock-in" by some carriers, Vodafone comes to mind.

So the developer version would get you "bare metal" Android 2.2, which according to this link (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/08/nexus-one-developer-phone.html) is standard Android 2.1, updated to 2.2 at first boot.

Comment: Yep, I have a developer Nexus one and can confirm there is no difference. It just doesn't have any carrier branding (a good thing)

Comment: there are two versions, but the only difference is which 3G bands it can use.  IIRC one is for 850/2100 the other is 900/2100